# How to load the documents in Android using Flutter packages

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I’m developing the Flutter application to load the documents from other sources and cloud.

I have used “flutter_webview_plugin” for that and it’s working on iOS to view all the documents. But android is not supporting for view the documents using webview.

Is flutter has any package for load the documents such as .doc, .pdf, .ppt, .xls in the Android.

Please advise your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if there is a solution, but in any case you can use native-android for this purpose.

Comment: You can try to combine some packages like `file_picker` (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/file_picker) which allows you to pick any file (and even restrict types) from an explorer in both platforms and then load that file with `flutter_full_pdf_viewer` (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer) that, for example, displays the PDF in a widget tree.
However, for all of those document types I'm not sure if there's anything already available.

Comment: Any update on it. ? How do you manage it? I am facing the same issue right now.